# Missing data with a SELECT in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database, postgresql, pdo

I can't find the problem here:

When typing that on my terminal:

```
SELECT album_id FROM users_albums WHERE user_id=1;
```

I have this on the terminal:

### album_id

```
    3
    4
```

(2 lignes)

This is my goal result.

But when I want to have the same result using PHP, doing this:

```
$albumsID = $this->_db->query("SELECT album_id FROM users_albums WHERE user_id=1");

$donnes = $albumsID->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($donnes);
```

The result of the var_dump in the php page is:

```
array(1) { ["album_id"]=> int(3) }
```

So I have only the first album_id (3), but not the second (4).

What i'm missing?

Comment: You want to use `fetchAll()`, as `fetch()` only returns the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only fetching 1 row using `fetch()`. If you want to fetch all rows, you can use:

```
$donnes = $albumsID->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

By having this:

```
$donnes = $albumsID->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This only returns into one row. You actually need to loop it:

```
while($donnes = $albumsID->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $donnes['album_id'];
    echo $id;
}
```

Also, `->fetchAll()` will also accomplish the same objective:

```
foreach($albumsID->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $donnes) {
    $id = $donnes['album_id'];
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: I thought fetch() returns all the data. Running good with fetchAll(), thanks

Comment: @AdrianSalas sure no prob, jereon was the one answered first glad these answers helped